OLS coefficients: importance of variables
I am using an OLS model to determine the importance of independent variables on the dependent vriable.
All variables are scaled.
I am currently interpreting the coefficients as follows :
Independent variable 1 coef $= 0.04$
Independent variable 2 coef $= 0.06$
Independent variable 3 coef $= 0.08$
Importance of variable 1 :
$$
\frac{0.04}{0.04 + 0.06 + 0.08} \\
= 0.22
$$
Therefore I am stating that independent variable 1 'explains' $22\%$ of the model.
However in the case that a coefficient is negative:
e.g.
Independent variable 1 coef $= 0.04$
Independent variable 2 coef $= - 0.06$
Independent variable 3 coef $= 0.08$
Is it valid to take the absolute of this coefficient (other wise I will have over $100\%$ in the final calculation) considering I am not interested in the movements of the variables, only how much they "explain" the model?

Welcome to Cross Validated! Isn't this what the partial $\eta^2$ ("eta-squared") does?

Thanks for your response, Im currently using OLS model so unsure how i would use the eta-squared. Is it possible to use the coeff in the way i mentioned? thank you!

We need to know a bit more about your design to describe how something like partial $\eta^{2}$ can be computed. However, you also note that your variables are scaled. If they are scaled to have mean 0 and SD 1 (including the dependent), then the coefficients can be compared to each other without taking any sort of ratio. This can be misleading, however.

As discussed here, partial $R^2$ are useful quantities for quantifying predictive information in non-collinear variables (when a group of variables has strong collinearities you need to get the partial $R^2$ for the entire group to avoid competition).  Also discussed there is the need to bootstrap any variable importance measure, because these are much more unstable than you might think.  It takes a large sample to be precise in estimating relative importance.
In the machine learning world, relative importance is gauged a variety of ways but the analyses seldom include uncertainty intervals.  Uncertainty intervals would expose the futility of approach in many settings.
You can also get bootstrap confidence intervals for importance rankings of predictors, as covered elsewhere in RMS.
